# How to find out the static and dynamic types of customized Exceptions

Tags: java, exception

First to the task: I got to print out a certain String which includes the dynamic and the static type of my customized Exceptions.
In a `try and catch`, I have to do the same thing with different ways of expressing the `catch` part.

I am a little confused about how to print out the static types and the dynamic types.
Can I also just work with `getClass()`

so just for a more precise explaination, here is my code so far:

```
    String s1 = "1 : ";
    String s2 = "Exception : ";
    String s3 = "UpdateTimeBeforeLastUpdateException ";
    String s4 = "UpdateTimeInTheFutureException ";
    try {
        outsourced(ts, cal, 1);
    }
    catch(UpdateTimeBeforeLastUpdateException exc1) {
        System.out.println(s1 + s2 + s3 + exc1);
    }
    catch(UpdateTimeInTheFutureException exc2) {
        System.out.println(s1 + s2 + s4 + exc2);
    }
}

public void testCatch2(TimeStamp ts, Calendar cal, int test) throws Exception {
    String s1 = "2 : ";
    String s2 = "Exception : ";
    String s3 = "UpdateTimeBeforeLastUpdateException ";
    String s4 = "UpdateTimeInTheFutureException ";
    try {
        outsourced(ts, cal, 2);
    }
    catch(UpdateTimeBeforeLastUpdateException | UpdateTimeInTheFutureException exc) {
        System.out.println();
    }
}

private void outsourced(TimeStamp ts, Calendar cal, int n) throws Exception {
    switch (n) {
    case 1:
        ts.updateWithExc1(cal);
        break;
    case 2:
        ts.updateWithExc2(cal);
        break;
    case 3:
        ts.updateWithExc3(cal);
        break;
    case 4:
        ts.updateWithExc4(cal);
        break;
    case 5:
        ts.updateWithExc5(cal);
        break;
    }
```

there are 3 more methods to come but my main problem is just the `catch` and `outprint` part

Answer (score 1):

If I got the question right, I assume that this may answer it:

```
try
{
    … // do something that causes an exception
}
catch( final OneException | TwoException e )
{
    if( e instanceof OneException e1 )
    {
        … // Handle OneException e1
    }
    else if( e instanceof TwoException e2 )
    {
        … // Handle TwoException e2
    }
    else throw new Error( "None of the expected exceptions caught" );
}
```

That `instanceof` syntax requires a later version of Java (14, I guess).

With the version 17 of Java (and the preview features enabled) it should be possible to use a `switch` statement, like this:

```
try
{
    … // do something that causes an exception
}
catch( final OneException | TwoException e )
{
    switch( e )
    {
        case OneException e1 -> e1.printStackTrace(); // Handle OneException e1
        case TwoException e2 -> System.out.println( e2.getMessage() ); // Handle TwoException e2
        default -> { throw new Error( "None of the expected exceptions caught" ); }
    }
}
```

Confessed, the in the second sample, the handling of the exceptions is lame … but it works!

Comment: wow yeah, it does answer my question! Thanks for the help:)

Answer (score 0):

You can use multi-catch statments. And in the catch block, you can call `getClass().getName()` on the exception object. Now, you will have a fully qualified name of the exception class. If you just want the class name, not the fully qualified name, you can use `String#split()` and pass in a dot as a regular expression (`\Q.\E`, if you don't enclose dot with `\Q` and `\E`, it means that we are saying to match any character, not the dot) and get the last element from the returned array.

Here is how you do it:
I am just rewriting your `testCatch2()`

```
public void testCatch2(TimeStamp ts, Calendar cal, int test) throws Exception {
    String s1 = "2 : ";
    String s2 = "Exception : ";
    try {
        outsourced(ts, cal, 2);
    } catch(UpdateTimeBeforeLastUpdateException | UpdateTimeInTheFutureException exc) {
        System.out.println(s1 + s2 + exc.getClass().getName());

        // If you don't want the fully qualified name, use the below statements.
        // String[] parts = exc.getClass().getName().split("\\Q.\\E");
        // System.out.println(s1 + s2 + parts[parts.length - 1]);
    }
}
```

Comment: with getClass() i get the overall classes name right? so in this case it would be exception right? and how do i get access to the customized exception which is a subtype(extends Exception) of Exception?

Comment: @SerkanBesim – `Object.getClass()` gives you the `Class` object for a given object, and `getClass().getName()` gives you the fully qualified class name (including the package name(s)). But String magic is not required to get just the class name without the packages, `getClass().getSimpleName()` does the job, too.

Comment: @SerkanBesim You have multi-catch block. So, when an exception is thrown, you will get that exception object only to the catch block here. So, when you call getClass(), it will be called on the right object. So, you will get the Class object for the right exception, whatever it can be, even it is very down in the hierarchy.

Comment: Thank you so much! Problem already solved:)